# Facebook. After approve permission wrong redirect link

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, redirect, permissions

so I have a little problem, when first time user use my app It is redirected to:

```
http://www.facebook.com/MY_APP.../?state=f5c913239670dc934fae1274a81fa538&code=AQAmY5k8gRRt7woNKmpc_6z2eHgT-2B3prjNEDYFma1KqpQDKob-CS_bWfqd0qPkQD-tGoVdKUK8twGZRnLhoiotpZ3SlBeo3uusfmMyWDYStv-D79RvQEP8m9M8S8GYlbN3x1eLEd4D3RajWokTNAhRP8a1VB9VSKAb35xXFzg3PkheRKHqjr-nex5jcjM7Nv2B_JEV1w8AzM2LJg2M9kAb#_=_
```

And I get error: `page not found`

Durring permission approvig my link is: `https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=456080124457246&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fpadekime.wu.lt%2Fplaukai%2Findex.php&state=2c46a86dae43af0467da756bc3e52779&scope=publish_stream%2Cphoto_upload`

I added redirect link and now It go to:

```
http://www.padekime.wu.lt/plaukai/kontekstas/?state=5abfd521df3c68ae55f26ad51a704743&code=AQDMmpZC-_Yxatq4xuAE60Tl2qW4pXCvDeghrbMGGu3Lg1X8zqrk-lvxRc3VOoYvgoLvATJhcsyykZnPoM7XI2sXih-nJhKrjx-HS3GFapELmC4KvX4KyN-VU-znHopkA-q_zcuIffJ0tY79CXPn7mo05BpxfvPntXaUAe7ymLf1p8Kg29eERaP5nw1dChbwwZ13FNY7BXD2ymAsFHPNH5zw#_=_
```

Possible to make that after permission approved go normally to my app `http://www.facebook.com/Padekime/app_456080124457246` without /?state=..... ?

My code now looks like:

```
<?php 
require_once('images/Facebook.php');

  $facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => '456080124457246',
    'secret' => 'e2956a6e1de8791363faedb1ef44c408',
  ));

  # Get User ID
  $user = $facebook->getUser();

  if ($user) {
    try {
$redirectUri = 'http://www.padekime.wu.lt/plaukai/kontekstas/';
  # Photo Caption
  $photoCaption = 'Patarimų plaukams sužinojau čia http://goo.gl/otwhf';

  # Absolute Path to your image.
  $imageUrl = 'http://padekime.wu.lt/plaukai/images/PlaukaiNeuzvedus.jpg'; // Example URL

  # Post Data for Photos API
  $post_data = array(
      'message' => $photoCaption,
      'url' => $imageUrl,
      'redirect_uri' => $redirectUri

  );

      $apiResponse = $facebook->api('/me/photos', 'POST', $post_data);

    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
      $user = null;
      error_log($e);
    }
  } else {
$redirectUri = 'http://www.padekime.wu.lt/plaukai/kontekstas/';
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl( array(
        'scope' => 'publish_stream,photo_upload',
        'redirect_uri' => $redirectUri
    ));
    echo("<script>top.location.href = '" . $loginUrl . "';</script>");
  }
?>
```

As I understand problem is somewhere here, but I cant solve it.

```
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl( array(
    'scope' => 'publish_stream,photo_upload'    
));
echo("<script>top.location.href = '" . $loginUrl . "';</script>");
```

So if you know something about this, please help me, thank you very much.

**SOLUTION:**

I added ?ref=ts to $redirectUri:

`$redirectUri = 'http://www.facebook.com/Padekime/app_456080124457246?ref=ts';`

Comment: In the future, do not add "solved" to the title of your question. Post your answer *as an answer*, and then accept your answer to "close" the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION:

I added ?ref=ts to $redirectUri:

$redirectUri = 'http://www.facebook.com/Padekime/app_456080124457246?ref=ts';